# Apache 2.2 MPM usage for different sites

Tags: php, apache, cpu-usage

Can one apache instance run different MPM's for different sites?

For example, I got a server with apache, and two sites: www.site1.com and www.site2.com.

Can I possibly have mpm_prefork_module on site1 and mpm_worker_module for site2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to start two instances of Apache, Listening on non overlapping ip:port combinations, to use two different MPM's.  You can't use a different MPM with just VirtualHost'ing.

Comment: Hi @covener, Can I ask you as well, there are directives in MPM settings. Do they share across the sites? I mean, if MaxClients set to 50 - that means, 50 clients for both in combination, rather than 50 clients for each site?

Comment: The mpm directives are global, not per site/vhost